# Get the first following div sibling

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write Xpath to uniquely identify one element
The document looks something like this

```
<AAA>
   <div>   </div>
   <div>   </div>
   <div>
      <div id='d'>YES</div>
   </div>
   <div>   </div>  ---> Want to select based on the mentioned sibling condition
   <div>   </div>

</AAA>
```

I want to select the div element who is following sibling of the div element, containing the child div element[containing YES].
I tried doing this which failed:

```
//following-sibling::div[@id='d']/div[contains(. , 'YES')]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPATH to select following-sibling `div` elements of any `div` containing `YES` will be:

```
//div[contains(., 'YES')]/following-sibling::div
```

In your current XML, the third `div` and it's child `div` both contain *YES* as their value. The child doesn't have a following-sibling here.
So, only the last two `div` elements(which are following-sibling to the third `div` in your XML) will be selected.

**EDIT**

```
//div[div[contains(., 'YES')]]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

This would select the first following-sibling `div` element of any `div` with a child `div`(with value *YES*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lingamurthy. I think i framed the question wrong. Please look at the edited one.

Comment: @Nik_stack So you want to select only the first following-sibling of the `div` that has a `div` child with value _YES_. Is it? And does `@id` has to do something here?

Comment: Yes. @id does not have any role here.

Comment: @Nik_stack Please look at my edit. I hope this does it.

Comment: This answer is correct +1, @Nik_stack now you should accept either this answer or the one by har07.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
//div[div[@id='d' and contains(.,'YES')]]/following-sibling::div[1]
```